# How to mass remove known Wi-Fi Preferred Networks in OS X?

Tags: wifi, macos, settings

In my list of Wi-Fi Preferred Networks I'm able to remove them 1 by 1, but that takes forever. Is there any way to select all the Network Names I want to remove and delete them at the same time?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can multi-select & delete from
System Prefs > Network > WiFI > Advanced…
 <kbd>Shift ⇧</kbd>  or  <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>  Click to select multiples, then hit the —  button underneath.

Note that this will also clear the same settings from any linked iDevice.

[image]

Comment: You just made my day.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but I think that this removal does not actually become active until you click "Apply" in the Network Preferences window underneath?

Comment: Nothing in Network prefs activates until Apply is clicked. If Apply is clickable, you need to click it, always.

Comment: why didn't I ever think of that (multi-select, like anywhere else)?!?!?! thanks!!